# Including third-party libraries in C applications

Tags: c, organization

I'm a bit naive when it comes to application development in C. I've been writing a lot of code for a programming language I'm working on and I want to include stuff from ICU (for internationalization and unicode support).

The problem is, I'm just not sure if there are any conventions for including a third party library. for something like readline where lots of systems are probably going to have it installed already, it's safe to just link to it (I think). But what about if I wanted to include a version of the library in my own code? Is this common or am I thinking about this all wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code requires 3rd party libraries, you need to check for them before you build. On Linux, at least with open-source, the canonical way to do this is to use Autotools to write a configure script that looks for both the presence of libraries and how to use them. Thankfully this is pretty automated and there are tons of examples. Basically you write a `configure.ac` (and/or a `Makefile.am`) which are the source files for `autoconf` and `automake` respectively. They're transformed into `configure` and `Makefile.in`, and `./configure` conditionally builds the Makefile with any configure-time options you specify.

Note that this is really only for Linux. I guess the canonical way to do it on Windows is with a project file for an IDE...

Answer (score 1):

If it is a .lib and it has no runtime linked libraries it gets complied into you code.  If you need to link to dynamic libraries you will have to assure they are there provide a installer or point the user to where they can obtain them.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about shipping your software off to end users and are worried about dependencies - you have to provide them correct packages/installers that include the dependencies needed to run your software, or otherwise make sure the user can get them (subject to local laws, export laws, etc, etc, etc, but that's all about licensing).

You could build your software and statically link in ICU and whatever else you use, or you can ship your software and the ICU shared libraries.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the OS you're targeting.  For Linux and Unix system, you will typically see dynamic linking, so the application will use the library that is already installed on the system.  If you do this, that means it's up to the user to obtain the library if they don't already have it.  Package managers in Linux will do this for you if you package your application in the distro's package format.

On Windows you typically see static linking, which means the application bundles the library and it will use that specific version.  many different applications may use the same library but include their own version.  So you can have many copies of the library floating around on your system.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with shipping a copy of the library with your code is that you don't get the benefit of the library's maintainers' bug fixes for free. Obscure, small, and unsupported libraries are generally worth linking statically.  Otherwise I'd just add the dependency and ensure that whatever packages you ship indicate it appropriately.

Comment: The problem is generally disagreement over what constitutes obscure, small, and unsupported. Users of strongly-package-managed systems like Debian and Ubuntu are likely to consider a huge number of libraries standard and "supported" or "maintained" if there's someone maintaining the package for their distribution, even if it's basically unmaintained upstream or has poor portability upstream and is difficult to install. If you introduce dependencies on such libraries, users of more obscure or DIY-type systems are sure to hate you for it...

Comment: @R: Good point. Being a Debian user is nice, and my BSD boxen don't generally need to run fancy stuff, but they do call it dependency hell for a reason.